# Angular 8 Reactive Form Validators

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular8, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have a FormControl in my Angular 8 app like this:

```
this.closingOrderFormGroup = this._fb.group({
   final_price: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required ] ),
});
```

I tried to add/remove **Validators.required** dynamically based on some radio button check as follows:

```
radioChange( event ) { 
    const finalPriceControl: any = this.closingOrderFormGroup.get('final_price');

    if ( event.value == 'completed' ) {
      finalPriceControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    }
    else if ( event.value == 'rejected' ) {
      finalPriceControl.setValidators(null);
    }
  }
```

But after set Validators null the FormControl  "status" is still Invalid. **How should I change the FormControl status?**

Comment: You have to call updateValueAndValidity()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe for value change in angular reactive form.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
        final_price: ['', [ Validators.required ] ]
    });

    this.formControlValueChanged();

}
```

//Subscribe this way

```
formControlValueChanged() {
    const finalPriceControl = this.loginForm.get('final_price');
    this.loginForm.get('final_price').valueChanges.subscribe(
        (mode: string) => {
            console.log(mode);
            if (mode === 'completed') {
                finalPriceControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
            } else if (mode === 'rejected') {
                finalPriceControl.clearValidators();
            }
            finalPriceControl.updateValueAndValidity();
        });
}
```

> Hope this helps :)

Comment: To make clear, the answer to the question here is the ‘updateValueAndValidity()’ bit